# Ошибка при прочтении JSON файла

Tags: android, json, twitch

Есть код, который получает JSON файл по ссылке LINK

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(**LINK**);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }
```

Затем, передает информацию в метод onPostExecute, который, допустим, просто выводит в лог эту информацию.

```
 @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);        
       try {
            //SONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "JSON  " + dataJsonObj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        }
```

Если указана ссылка LINK на файл с объектами и ключами/значениями, например
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/igromania

> {"stream":null,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/igromania","channel":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/igromania"}}

То информация выводится в лог. А если указана ссылка на файл БЕЗ объектов, но с ключами/значениями, например 
http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ajfafaasf

> {"error":"Bad Request","message":"Requests must be made over SSL","status":400}

то в лог ничего не выводится и выбрасывается несколько исключений:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ajfafaasf
```

из последней строки понял, что файл не найден, но перейдите по ссылке и проверьте сами, он там есть. В чём проблема здесь? Может можно каким-то образом сделать проверку на наличие массивов или объектов(которые, уже ,в свою очередь, включают в себя ключи/значения)
Пытался как можно понятнее изложить свою проблему, надеюсь Вы сможете подсказать, чем лечить эту проблему.

Comment: Выведите `Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);` перед созданием `JSONObject` и посмотрите, реально ли там json лежит.

Comment: @Suvitruf программа даже не доходит до вывода, ошибка вылетает еще в doInBackground`e..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам сервер отвечает с ошибкой 400 в статусе. В случае статуса больше либо равному 400 (это значит, что возникла ошибка) ответ от сервера будет лежать не в `urlConnection.getInputStream()`, а в  `urlConnection.getErrorStream()`

Итого, вам нужно проверять:

```
InputStream inputStream
if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
} else {
    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
}
```

Comment: Интересно, я не знал об этом, думал, что при ошибке ответ будет лежать там же. Обязательно попробую, спасибо Вам за ответ!